# Initializing new object with parameters fail without symbols

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

```
def initialize(user=nil, attributes={})
      @user = user
      (self.class.car_fields & attributes.keys.map{|i| i.to_sym }).each do |f|
        car[f] =  attributes[f] if attributes.key?(f)
      end
      validate!
    end
```

#### Method Call

```
 attributes = { "has_car" => "true", "has_truck" => "true", "has_boat" => "true", "color" => "blue value", "size" => "large value" }
Car.new(user, attributes)
```

the attributes do not update for validation in my model.

However, if I pass a hash with all symbols it works.

```
 attributes_symbols = { :has_car => "true", :has_truck => "true", :has_boat => "true", :color => "blue value", :size=> "large value" }

Car.new(user, attributes_symbols)
```

#### Why is it that when I pass symbols my model see the fields, but in the former case it acts as though the fields were never passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in

```
attributes.keys.map{|i| i.to_sym }
```

You're mapping each key to a symbol, and then accessing them in `attributes` as a symbol, when they're string keys.

So you end up doing something like:

```
{ "has_car" => "true", "has_truck" => "true", "has_boat" => "true", ... }[:has_car]
# nil
```

---

A possible solution would be to create a new variable, invoking [`with_indifferent_access`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-with_indifferent_access) on `attributes`:

```
indifferent_access_attributes = attributes.with_indifferent_access
(self.class.car_fields & indifferent_access_attributes.keys.map(&:to_sym)).each do |field|
  seller[field] = indifferent_access_attributes[field]
end
```

Another one would be to define just a format of keys and work with that during the whole process. So, don't map to symbol the `attributes` keys.

Comment: I am now getting an error, NoMethodError (undefined method `with_indifferent_access' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x00007ffc379ebac0>):